How to optionally plot a file in gnuplot
(Note: this question was heavily edited from the previous version)
I'd like a plot command in gnuplot to plot a different number of datasets in different circumstances, e.g.
set multiplot layout 3, 1

array names[3] = ["foo", "bar", baz"]

do for [i=1:3] {
    background = names[i]."-bg.txt"
    foregroundA = names[i]."-fg.txt"
    foregroundB = (i == 2 ? "< ./stuff" : "/dev/null")
    plot background u 1:2:3 w image palette, \
        foregroundA u 1:2 w lines, \
        foregroundB u 1:2 w points
}

where first and third plot should include three datasets (background, foregroundA and foregroundB), while the second one should include only two (background and foregroundA).  Using "/dev/null" as foregroundB when it shouldn't plot anything works, except for a warning: Skipping data file with no valid points.  Is there something I can use instead that works without warnings?  (I'd rather not just unroll the loop by hand, because in my actual script I also have lots of other stuff before the plot command and I'd rather not duplicate code unnecessarily, and I'd rather not just redirect gnuplot's stderr to /dev/null because I don't want to silence any other warnings I might get.)

Is the plot command identical for the two files? Or is it actually something like plot file1 u 1:2, file2 u 3:4?

@theozh they're different, something like
array names[3] = ["foo", "bar", baz"]; do for [i=1:3] { background = names[i]."-bg.txt"; foregroundA = names[i]."-fg.txt"; foregroundB = (i == 1 ? "< ./stuff" : "/dev/null"); plot background u 1:2:3 w image palette, foregroundA u 1:2 w lines, foregroundB u 1:2 w points }

ok. Could you please edit your question accordingly and describe in detail what you actually want to achieve. Otherwise we might run into a XY-problem. And code is easier to read in the question than in the comments.

@theozh done -- is what I want clear enough now?

Problem solved, question answered? If you've found another solution please share it.

@theozh I decided to just ignore the warnings -- I've encountered several other circumstances where I want to plot a file that may or may not be empty (e.g. plot [][:1.2] "file", "< awk '$2 > 1.2 {print $1, 1.2}' file" pt "↑" notitle where file may or may not contain any entries with $2 > 1.2)

Just put the actual file path instead of /dev/null.
Read this post for more details.

There is no "actual file" to be used -- I need to plot "file1.txt" plus another file in certain circumstances and "file1.txt" alone in other circumstances.

For some (yet unknown) reason |ARGV| did not work for me.
So, but the following using a plot for ... loop  did. It might need to be adapted to your detailed plot command and needs. And some filenames (especially with spaces) might need special treatment. But in the simplest case to just plot two files with identical plot command it works fine in a loop. Furthermore, it does not depend on the operating system. It should work for Linux as well as for Windows.
Script: SO78710291.gp
### plotting files depending on argument
FILE1 = "Data1.dat"
FILE2 = ARGC>0 ? ARG1 : ''

FILES = FILE1.' '.FILE2

plot for [FILE in FILES] FILE u 1:2 w lines
### end of script

If I call this

from gnuplot console via call "SO78710291.gp" or
from command line via gnuplot -p -c "SO78710291.gp"

Data1.dat will be plotted (without warning)
If I call this

from gnuplot console via call "SO78710291.gp" "Data2.dat" or
from command line via gnuplot -p -c "SO78710291.gp" "Data2.dat"

Data1.dat and Data2.dat will be plotted (assuming the plot command should be identical for the files).

In my actual scenario, the plotting specification is not identical for all files (also, some of the filenames include spaces --are actually "< ./command"-- so I can't use for [FILE in FILES] with FILES as a space-separated string): it's more like array names[3] = ["foo", "bar", baz"]; do for [i=1:3] { background = names[i]."-bg.txt"; foregroundA = names[i]."-fg.txt"; foregroundB = (i == 1 ? "< ./stuff" : "/dev/null"); plot background u 1:2:3 w image palette, foregroundA u 1:2 w lines, foregroundB u 1:2 w points }

After OP's clarification, here is another solution allowing completely different plot commands depending on a condition. Before that, I unsuccessfully tried with plotting NaN or using macros (check help macros). The latter basically works, but for a reason which I don't yet understand, this doesn't work in a loop.
So, the "trick" is to use evaluate (check help evaluate). With this, you can construct any string, e.g. using variables, conditions and formatting (sprintf()) and later evaluate that string. You might have to pay attention about the use of single and double quotes.
Data:
Since I prefer fully working examples, in order to test the script below, first you have to create a few files.
For simplicity the files foo-bg.txt, bar-bg.txt, baz-bg.txt are identical:
1  1  0
1  2  1
2  1  2
2  2  3

Similar for foo-fg.txt, bar-fg.txt, baz-fg.txt:
1   1
2   1
2   2
1   2

And the file stuff.txt:
1.0  1.0
1.5  1.5
2.0  2.0

Script:
### plotting files depending on a condition
reset session

set palette grey
set key out noautotitle

array names[3] = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

cmd1(i) = sprintf('"%s-bg.txt" u 1:2:3 w image ti "%s background"', names[i], names[i])
cmd2(i) = sprintf(', "%s-fg.txt" w l lw 3 lc "red" ti "%s foreground"', names[i], names[i])
cmd3(i) = i==2 ? ', "stuff.txt" u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "green" ti "stuff"' : ''

cmd(i) = "plot ".cmd1(i).cmd2(i).cmd3(i)

set multiplot layout 3,1
    do for [i=1:3] {
        set title 'i = '.i
        print cmd(i)    # just for double check command
        eval cmd(i)
    }
unset multiplot
### end of script

Result:
plot "foo-bg.txt" u 1:2:3 w image ti "foo background", "foo-fg.txt" w l lw 3 lc "red" ti "foo foreground"
plot "bar-bg.txt" u 1:2:3 w image ti "bar background", "bar-fg.txt" w l lw 3 lc "red" ti "bar foreground", "stuff.txt" u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "green" ti "stuff"
plot "baz-bg.txt" u 1:2:3 w image ti "baz background", "baz-fg.txt" w l lw 3 lc "red" ti "baz foreground"


